# Subharmonic functions with reasonably non absolute continuous laplacian

Tags: measure-theory, potential-theory

Does it exist a compact supported measure $\mu$ in the plane $\Bbb R^2$ with the following two properties?

1) Points have $\mu$-measure zero,

2) If $\Delta u=\mu$, then the polar set of $u$ has positive $\mu$-measure.

($\Delta$ is the laplacian and the polar set of $u$ is the set of the points where $u=-\infty$).

NOTE

a) Condition 2) is independent of the choice of $u$ because the polar set does not change by addition of a harmonic function.

b) $\mu$ cannot be absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure because polar sets of subharmonic functions have zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: If $\mu$ is a uniform measure on the standard (ternary) Cantor set $C$, then the logarithmic potential of $\mu$ is infinite on $C$ — I think this answers your question?

Comment: An easier example is the equilibrium measure of the generalized Cantor set of zero capacity (see the book of Nevanlinna, Analytic functions, or <a href="https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82601512.pdf">this article</a>.

Comment: To Mateusz: by uniform measure you mean that the measure of a ball only depends on the radius?

Comment: To Alexander. My computer doesn’t open the core article. Could you tell me the reference or, if it is short, just send to claudio.rea@gmail.com ?